# value of select and radio using php

Tags: php

i'm using php4 to develoope a small application , i have a small form , including a radiobox , and a selectbox..
for the insert of the data , it works ,now i want to try update my form , i have a small problem ,i would like  to get the value of the radiobox that the user check it, and same for the select..
any one can help me please.
here is my code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php 
include('connexion.php');
$id=$_GET['idp'];
$req="SELECT * FROM `personne` where id='$id'";

$res=mysql_query(($req));
$ligne=mysql_fetch_row($res);
?>
<form method="get" action="updatesubmit.php">
<table>
<tr><td>Nom:</td><td><input type="text" 
 value="<?php echo $ligne[1] ?>" name="nom">*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Prenom:</td><td><input type="text" 
 value="<?php echo $ligne[2] ?>" name="prenom">*</td></tr>
 <tr><td>email:</td><td><input type="email" 
 value="<?php echo $ligne[3] ?>"  name="email">*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Numero Tel:</td><td><input type="text" 
 value="<?php echo $ligne[4]   ?>"  name="tel"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sexe:</td><td>H:<input type="radio"  name="sexe" value="homme">
F:<input type="radio" required name="sexe" value="femme">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Pays:</td><td>
<select name="pays">
<option>Australie</option>
<option>FRance</option>
<option>Maroc</option>
<option>Tunisie</option>
<option>USA</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="s'inscrire"></td></tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should care about mysql injection by using PDO or :
$id = (int) $_GET['idp'];
For your select, in case the data is stored in $ligne[6]:
`<select name="pays">
    <option value='Australie' <?php echo ($ligne[6]=='Australie')? 'selected' : '' ; ?> >Australie</option>
    <option value='France' <?php echo ($ligne[6]=='France')? 'selected' : '' ; ?> >France</option>
    <option value='Maroc' <?php echo ($ligne[6]=='Maroc')? 'selected' : '' ; ?> >Maroc</option>
    <option value='Tunisie' <?php echo ($ligne[6]=='Tunisie')? 'selected' : '' ; ?> >Tunisie</option>
    <option value='USA' <?php echo ($ligne[6]=='USA')? 'selected' : '' ; ?> >USA</option>
   </select>`

and for your radiobox, in case the data is stored in $ligne[5]:

```
H:<input type="radio"  name="sexe" value="homme" <?php echo ($ligne[5]=='homme')? 'checked' : '' ;?> >
F:<input type="radio"  name="sexe" value="femme" <?php echo ($ligne[5]=='femme')? 'checked' : '' ;?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

The value should be reside in $_GET['sexe'], however if it's doesn't return which mean user never select neither of the radio input.

```
...
$sexe = (isset($_GET['sexe']) ? $_GET['sexe'] : '');
...
```

- removed the **required** tag on sexe=femme; use JavaScript/jQuery instead to do the interactive validation.